# Understanding sort command in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am trying to sort a file called *data* for learning purposes. Its given in my textbook.

```
5 27
2 12
3 33
23 2
-5 11
15 6
14 -9
```

Q1) What is the order of just `sort data` in this case ?

Q2) I am working in one folder. `sort data` works, but `sort +1n data` does not. Why ?
    I typed it exactly like in the book and I get this error -

```
sort: cannot read: +1n: No such file or directory
```

**EDIT -**  The book wants to skip column 1 and sort by column 2. Thats why +n might be used.

I use lubuntu 13 to learn unix bash scripting.

*PS -* Here is the output of `sort data`

```
14 -9
15 6
2 12
23 2
3 33
-5 11
5 27
```

Comment: You're lacking the flag `-k`, to define [*key ranges*](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html). Note they are **ranges**! Not **columns**!

Comment: Why could Q1 be a question? can't you just try it?

Comment: @Kent - tried it, but there seemed to be a random order. Not sure if there was any meaning to it. I think I'll post the output of that too.

Comment: if this is for learning purposes, the best way to learn is to do `man sort` or even `sort --help`  I think @Rubens has your answer though.

Comment: The output you posted from `sort data` is bizarre. On my system, the `-5` comes before `14` (because `-` comes before `1`). What version of `sort` are you running? (That is: what does `sort --version` print?)

Comment: @blasto you must have a really old book

Comment: @Nirk - yes, 2003. http://www.amazon.com/Unix-Shell-Programming-3rd-Edition/dp/0672324903/ But we are not allowed to ask suggestions for books here :( Anyway, what do you recommend ? I have no knowledge of UNIX, OS, Linux. Only interested in learning bare minimum and scripting for now.

Comment: @blasto that argument style (the +1n) was eliminated in modern versions of sort.  See my response

Comment: Now run: `LC_ALL=C sort data` and see how the output is different. The old `+1n` notation should be avoided; use the new `-k` notation instead, observing that `+1` counts from field 0 but `-k` counts from field 1.

Comment: @ruakh - sort (GNU coreutils) 8.20

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - can you show me how to sort based on "column1" only and "column2" only. thanks.

Comment: `sort -k1,1 data` sorts only on column 1; `sort -k2,2 data` sorts only on column 2.  You can apply options such as `n` and `r` either globally (`-n`, `-r`) or per sort criterion (`sort -k1,1r -k2,2n data`).  You'll need some more comprehensive data to show how the sorts work.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I did sort -k2,2n data and it works the way I want it, ie sort by column 2, considering it as n-umbers. BTW, what is this X,X format ? why not just X ?

Comment: In part, RTFM for [`sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html), but the number before the comma is the start column, and the number after is the end column.  Using `sort -k1 data` is the same as `sort data` and means sort by column 1, then by column 2, then by column 3, ...  You can also use `sort -k1.2 data` which sorts starting with the second character in column 1, etc.  Note that on any specific system, including Linux in particular, the `sort` command often has options not defined by POSIX.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - thanks. makes sense now. Is there a command to find out whether my linux distro uses posix, xyz-ix or whatever ? Is there a way to download some posix versions of these commands on my linux and run those instead (did that even make any sense) ?

Comment: Given that it is Linux, you almost invariably have GNU `sort`, which is part of [`coreutils`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html).  The GNU utilities usually hew close to the POSIX standard for the basic functionality, but usually have extra facilities too (if only because POSIX doesn't use multi-letter options but GNU does).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - yes, one of the comments above asked me to do sort --help and that resulted in sort (GNU coreutils) 8.20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` by default sorts the entire line lexicographically, so the first sort will be

```
-5 11
14 -9
15 6
2 12
23 2
3 33
5 27
```

`-` comes before `1` (check the ASCII codes for each)

According to the posix standard, the aforementioned sort is correct.  GNU SORT (the version used in ubuntu) appears to deviate.

The `+1n` argument also stems from older versions of sort:

> Earlier versions of this standard also allowed the - number and + number options. These options are no longer specified by POSIX.1-2008 but may be present in some implementations.
>
> First, the zero-based counting used by sort is not consistent with other utility conventions.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html

Putting the facts together, older versions of sort treated -1 as if it were `-k 2`, so you should use `-k2 -n` in ubuntu.

Comment: In my ubuntu, -5 comes between 3 and 5 by default.

Comment: @MartinZhang digging through the posix standard, its clear that ubuntu is wrong here

Comment: It is locale-dependent.  Set `LC_ALL=C` and the output of `sort` is different (as claimed here).

Comment: My LC related environment variables are zh_CN.UTF-8. After exporting LC_ALL=C, I get exact the same order as yours. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - wow ! Locale dependency ? Who would have thought ? How do I find out what my locale is and what is the definition of sort here ?

Comment: @blasto: I think Nirk is over-claiming — not accounting for locale-sensitivity.  You find your locale by looking at the environment variables that affect it — LANG, LC_ALL, LC_COLLATE, LC_NUMERIC, LC_TIME, LC_MONETARY, LC_CTYPE, LC_MESSAGES (and possibly others).  Try `man locale` to find out more (works on Mac OS X, listing information for `locale` command); or `man setlocale`.