# How to get the `sort` shell command to compare raw bytes?

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, posix, locale

It [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243984/understanding-sort-command-in-bash) [like](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) the posix `sort`
command line utility will do some [fancy locale based shenanegans](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_02) to compare the given strings.

I scanned the man page but could not seem to find a way to get it to use the raw byte values instead.
Is there a way to get `sort` (I have the GNU coreutils version) to behave like
`qsort(array_of_my_strings, N, strcmp)` would in `C`? Solutions using another tool then `sort` would be fine too.

For demonstration, I currently get:

```bash
printf "\xC3\xBC\n\x76\n" | sort
ü
v
```

because the german umlaut `ü` seems to be compared as u which comes before v, despite `\xC3` being larger than `\x76`.

What i want is

```bash
printf "\xC3\xBC\n\x76\n" | sort --raw-bytes-please
v
ü
```

Comment: Use the C locale: `printf ... | LC_ALL=C sort` (not `C.UTF-8`, which some distros have as a default).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thanks a lot! If this was an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: Haven't added an answer yet because I find it hard to believe this isn't a duplicate, hence spending some time looking for a preexisting instance. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531674/linux-sort-unexpected-output gets to the right answer, but it's not really the same question; likewise for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64176292/how-unix-sort-command-handles-expressions-with-different-character-sizes).

Comment: Understandable^^ I of course searched aswell but didn't find anything for what it's worth.

Comment: `sort --raw-bytes-please`?  How would that handle something like a raw `\n` character embedded in what should be one "line" of input?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: As I think the example demonstrates, I still want `\n` to be the line delimiter. I'm aware of `-z`, but my usecase doesn't demand it.

Comment: @ChrisB But you didn't explicitly rule out `0x0A` being one of your input raw bytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Collation order and (multi-byte) character type are influenced by your locale. The locale name for disabling multibyte and locale-aware behaviors is `C`.

Thus:

```
LC_COLLATE=C LC_CTYPE=C sort
```

...will set only the character type and the collation order (assuming `LC_ALL` isn't set, in which case they would be ignored).

---

As a big hammer, you can also use:

```
LC_ALL=C sort
```

albeit with side effects such as changing the language used for printing error messages &c to the strings originally written by `sort`'s developers with no translation tables in effect.